# Запрос BETWEEN, вывод всех дат в промежутке

Tags: sql, mariadb

Делаю запрос с группировкой и условию по дате:

```
SELECT 
    count(*) AS `cnt`, 
    DATE(dt) AS `dt`
FROM mydates 
    WHERE DATE(dt) BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-25'
GROUP BY DATE(dt);
```

Соотвественно, если за определенную дату нет данных, этой строки и нет в результате. Необходимо чтобы запрос возвращал все строки (в данном случае 25), а если нет данных за эту дату, должен быть 0.

Comment: А версия сервера - это большой секрет? ну и, чтобы два раза не бегать - покажите структуру таблицы, и скажите. каков порядок количества записей в ней.

Comment: нет, конечно не секрет, просто думал что особой роли это не играет. Distrib 10.3.22-MariaDB. В таблице 3 колонки. id INT(11), data VARCHAR(100), dt(DATETIME)